# How can I get the Facebook vanity URL from UID?

Tags: android, facebook, firebase

I'm currently working with some code that enables me to open the facebook app to the proper profile, but I'd like to know, for users without facebook app installed, how can I create a usable link to a specific profile page using UIDs stored in Firebase using the code in my catch block?

I'm using this method:

```
    public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context, String uid) {

    try {
        context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0); /
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("fb://profile/"+uid)); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/"+ uid(or something))); 
    }
}
```

Thank you!

-T

Comment: How does this relate to Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/profile.php?id="+ uid` will only work with the *global* user id.

Since your app only gets an app-scoped user id, you need to use the form

```
https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/{app-scoped id here}/
```

This is what the `link` field of the user object returns as well.

Comment: this works wonderfully for opening the page using a browser.  How would I go about retrieving the profile page for the app though?  I tried using `fb://page/app_scoped_user_id/{uid}` and `fb://page/{uid}` to no avail.  Thanks!

Comment: Just went with this option, As far as I read, the native facebook app doesn't take app_scoped_user_id.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id="+ uid));
```

Comment: Thank you!  I feel like this is closer to the right answer.  Although, whenever the page opens up, it says "Sorry, this content isn't available right now" do you happen to have any ideas as to why this is happening?